# Appstore takes time based on screens

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I have an app, A small app with 4-5 screens, I remember appstore usually takes 1-2 days.

So my question is if i have another app that haves 80 screens, Is the time to be approve is the same or it will take more time ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is specific to app store submission policies and procedures; not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all App Store usually approves application in 24 hours as per new rules. So all applications with average features will get approval.

Here is an official statement from Apple Team :

> On average, 50% of apps are reviewed in 24 hours and over 90% are
>   reviewed in 48 hours. If your submission is incomplete, review times
>   may be further delayed or your app may be rejected. Once your app has
>   been reviewed, its status will be updated and you will be notified.

So the App Store approval time will not vary according to the number of screens application have. But It can be on basis of complexity of features application have. On basis of that it can take time.

I have seen so many apps having 20-30 screens get approval in 24 hours & on the other side some of the applications have hardly 4-5 screens but have some lengthy advance features which needs more detailed review time takes more time.

But still as apple team mentioned in the official statement maximum time in the 90% cases is 48 hours only. So within 2 days they will approve your application even if it has more screens.

Hope this helps to everyone.